# renameTo fail sometimes when renaming file downloaded using Download Manager

Tags: android

I am downloading a file using Download Manager. If the file is already downloaded then the download manager append "-1" in front of the file name. Now I want to delete the old file with original if it is already present and then try to rename new file. I am doing this after the file has been downloaded so that old file is not delete prior to download of new file. Below is the code I have been using.

```
final File NewFile = new File(FileDirectory, FileNameWithoutExtension + "_" + DateMillis);

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(FileUri);
            request.setDescription("Test Description");
            request.setTitle("Download");
            request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/MyFiles", FileNameWithoutExtension + "_" + DateMillis);
```

Below is the code for Broadcast Receiver. I am not putting all of the code. Just the important line of code inside onReceive method.

```
String uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));                                 
File LatestFileDownloaded = new File(uriString);
String tmpName = uri.getLastPathSegment();

// Here I am deleting all the extra files with the same name but different appended letters
File[] extraFiles = FileDirectory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                                            return pathname.getName().contains(FileNameWithoutExtension + "_");
                                        }
                                    });

                                    if (extraFiles != null) {
                                        for (File extraFile : extraFiles) {
                                            if (!extraFile.getName().equals(tmpName)) {
                                                extraFile.delete();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
```

Piece of code to rename the file here,

```
if (!LatestFileDownloaded .getName().equals(FileNameWithoutExtension  + "_" + NodeDateMillis)) {
                                        LatestFileDownloaded.renameTo(NewFile );
                                        LatestFileDownloaded.delete();
                                    }
```

So for example, if the file MyFile_1410642204000 (Without any extension) is present and download manager download a new file then the new file will be saved with the name MyFile_1410642204000-1. Now MyFile_1410642204000-1 should be renamed to MyFile_1410642204000 and Old file MyFile_1410642204000-1 should be deleted but it is not. So on SDCard MyFile_1410642204000-1 is present.

Kindly check the code that why the file is not being renamed and what is wrong with my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem because the file is now renamed successfully every time. I am not sure 100% that this was the only issue that failed the file from getting renamed. The file Uri from Download Manager was like this,

```
/file://storage/emulated/0/MyFiles/
```

and the path I have created for file was without the file:/ prefix,

```
/storage/emulated/0/MyFiles/
```

I just removed the "/file:/" from the Uri and the file was successfully renamed.